# Relationship between incomplete gamma function and error function

Tags: probability, integration, normal-distribution, gamma-function, error-function

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+sqrt%28x%29+e%5E%28-x%29+dx+from+a+to+infty) verifies the following result:

> For $a > 0$, $$\int_a^\infty x^{1/2} e^{-x} \, dx = \int_{\sqrt{a}}^\infty e^{-x^2} \, dx + \sqrt{a} e^{-a}.$$

Is there a simple proof of this fact?

I tried to prove this using probability.
If $X \sim \chi^2_3$, then $$P(X \ge a) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_a^\infty x^{1/2} e^{-x} \, dx,$$
and if $Z \sim N(0,1)$, then $$P(Z > \sqrt{a/2}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{\sqrt{a/2}}^\infty e^{-u^2/2} \, du = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{\sqrt{a}}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx.$$

I'm unable to see the connection, and also unsure of how to deal with the other term $\sqrt{a} e^{-a}$.

Comment: Let $y = \sqrt{x}$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

I thought Integration by Parts helps?

$$\int_a^{\infty}\sqrt{x}e^{-x}dx=\underbrace{-\sqrt{x}e^{-x}\Bigg\vert_a^{\infty}}_{\sqrt{a}e^{-a}}+\underbrace{\int_a^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{2\sqrt{x}}dx}_{I_1}$$

What happens when you substitute $\displaystyle \sqrt{x}=t$ in $I_1$ ?